# sending date (UK format) from datepicker to mysql inodb table (US format) coding in model file

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i m trying to insert date in mysql table using CI 
my code for the datepicker is :

```
<div class="well well-lg">
<div class="col-md-6 input-group">
    <input type="text"  name="datep" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('datep'); ?>" class="form-control datep" id="datep" placeholder="Saisissez la date de parution">
    <label class="input-group-addon btn" for="datep">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </label>                    
</div>
</div>
```

the dateformat in datepicker config is : dd-mm-yyyy
and displayed like that dd-mm-yyyy

the problem is when i m trying to insert it in the table 
this yhe code in the MODEL file :

```
    function add_livre($params)
{

    $this->db->insert('livre',$params);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

always i have 0000-00-00 value for this date